# CircleCI with Rspec getting LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec_junit_formatter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, circleci

**Rails 7.0.0.alpha2**

**Circle CI**

**Rspec**

using default setup from
https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-demo-ruby-rails

Circle CI crashes with:

```
bundler: failed to load command: rspec (/home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rspec)
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec_junit_formatter
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:235:in `require'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:235:in `rescue in custom_formatter'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:232:in `custom_formatter'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:183:in `find_formatter'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:152:in `add'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:974:in `add_formatter'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:118:in `block in load_formatters_into'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:118:in `each'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:118:in `load_formatters_into'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:24:in `configure'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:132:in `configure'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:99:in `setup'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.10.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
  /home/circleci/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<top (required)>'

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

fixed with:

add to `Gemfile` and run bundle install

```
gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
```